# Wordpress function theme redirect determined by user IP address

Tags: wordpress

**THE IDEA**

I would like to develop a new wordpress theme, whilst my old theme stays active during the new theme development.

The function which will do the theme redirect will go in the current activated theme functions.php - and I will manually type **my theme name** and **my IP** into the function.

Would be awesome if you could add an array of IP's so clients can check progress.

**PROBLEMS I CAN THINK OF...**

1. New content I add to the wordpress cms, will appear on the live theme - ***Yes, this will happen, but in my situation, my current live theme is just a holding page, with theme template files redirecting via php header redirects to the home page - and there are no loops to see any worpress content***
2. A delay/flash may appear between pages loading - ***This is also not an issue for me as this is only a dev site, and this problem will disappear upon go live***

that is all the problems I can think of, if anyone can think of other possible problems please post :-)

**FUNCTION CODE**

This code below is not working...

```
    // THEME IP REDIRECT
    add_filter('template', 'dev_theme');
    add_filter('option_template', 'dev_theme');
    add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'dev_theme');
    function dev_theme($theme) {
        if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX' ) {
            return 'development-theme-name';
        }
        return $theme
    }
```

If anybody thinks they could solve this question, it would hugely helpful and a pretty awesome function.

Obviously depends whether there are any compilations with the idea.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a development server for building your new theme. Copy everything over to another virtual host on that server or to your local machine, including your database. Follow the instructions for [moving a wordpress site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress). Then develop your theme there and move it to your live site when ready.

If you really must develop your theme on your live website, you can swap them out with filters like so...

```
add_filter('template', 'dev_theme');
add_filter('option_template', 'dev_theme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'dev_theme');
function dev_theme($theme) {
    return 'twentyten';
}
```

Comment: My issue is that I am capturing data using gravity forms on the holding page, and I'd rather just do it via a theme redirect. Your solution is the cleanest way, but it's just easier for me to do it this way and avoid doing data base stuff. Thanks

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the pointers, I'm not massively au fait with php and writing functions, what I've done is not working, please see my post above for attempted code. Am I understanding right that 'twentyten is the returned theme for what ever condition is written inside this function?

Comment: That is correct, however, in your example above, if the ip doesn't match you still need to return the current theme name so add `return $theme` to the end of that function. If you don't return anything when the ip doesn't match, it will break your live theme.

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm struggling to get this to work - I don't suppose you could help me further by getting my code up to scratch. I'm not quite sure what is happening so can't seem to get it to work. Really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch_theme` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme